# Java8で「AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding」は使用可能でしょうか

Tags: java, security

Java8(Oracle)で使用可能な暗号化アルゴリズムについて

```
Set<String> algorithms = Security.getAlgorithms("Cipher");
```

で一覧が取得可能であると思っているのですが、

```
AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
```

が一覧にありません。
ですが、

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

と指定しても暗号化/復号化できているようです。

実は一覧に表示されないだけで、AES/CBC/PKCS5Paddingを使用しても問題はないのでしょうか。
もしかしたらデフォルトのAESが使用されECBで動作しているのでは、と少し不安です。

見づらくて恐縮ですが、以下にテストで使用したコードを添付します。

```
//鍵長は128ビット。これより長い鍵を使用する場合、ポリシーファイルの書き換えが必要
String key = "Pfz9B2PZqKttkwta";
//暗号化ルーチンに異なる初期値を与えるためだけのもの：16バイト固定
String iv = "hhk0zZToc6MGt76h";
//  private String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/NOPADDING";
private String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private String CIPER = "AES";

private enum MODE {
    ENCRYPT,
    DECRYPT
}

public TestAes() {}

public TestAes(String key, String iv) {
    this.key = key;
    this.iv = iv;
}

public String encrypt(String rawData){
    try {
        Cipher cipher = cipherUtil(MODE.ENCRYPT);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(rawData.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String decrypt(String encryptedData){
    try {
        Cipher cipher = cipherUtil(MODE.DECRYPT);
        byte[] decodedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedData);
        byte[] decryptData = cipher.doFinal(decodedData);
        return new String(decryptData);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private Cipher cipherUtil(MODE mode) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), CIPER);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

    int encryptMode = (mode == MODE.ENCRYPT) ? Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE : Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE;
    cipher.init(encryptMode, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

    return cipher;
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

使用可能です。
なぜならばhttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.htmlに
「Javaプラットフォームの実装は、すべて次の標準のCipher変換とカッコ内の鍵サイズをサポートする必要があります。」とあり、"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"は含まれています。

Security.getAlgorithms(serviceName)で返されるのは「アルゴリズムや型の名前(Signature、MessageDigest、Cipher、Mac、KeyStoreなど)」ということですので、「フィードバック・モードおよびパディング方式」は含まれないのかと思います。

Comment: 自分の環境(Windows 64bit jre1.8.0_40)でSecurity.getAlgorithms("Cipher")を出力してみたところ、「フィードバック・モードおよびパディング方式」も含まれた文字列が列挙されました。たしかにその中に"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"はないのですが、まあ公式ドキュメントを信用するべきでしょう…。念のためECBを指定したものと結果を比較してみるといいかもしれませんね。